# Android filter list of items

Tags: java, android, list

In an Android app I have a list of Items which consist of name and Category. Items and categories are stored in Android's SQLite database.

```
class Item{
    Long id;
    String name;
    Category category;
}

class Category{
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

- User can select categories using ComboBox list shown in dialog
- and then search items of selected categories by name.
- List should be filtered by categories when user click "OK" button in categories dialog
- and by name when user type some text in SearchView.

How to do the filtering in proper way?

- I think that filtering both categories and name on every character typed in SearchView isn't good way in term of performance.
- On the other hand filtering both atributes seperately produces additional list:

  - 1. Full list
  - 2. Items from full list filtered by categories
  - 3: Items from previous list fitlered by name.
- The other option I thought of is to query the database on SearchView text change to get desired result instead of filtering the full list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not a simple question. All developers do it differently. I suggest few things:

1. Make select on database only once, when user wrote first 1 or maybe 2 chars or choose category.
2. Remember selected from database list.   Let's name it - originalList. Visible list keep on the other object like filteredList.
3. Use something to avoid filtering everytime. If you know what is reactive programming you can use it's features. If you want to do it in oldschool way, you can for example make a task/job for filtering, which will be canceled, when new filter order will apear. In that way you have always 0 or 1 ongoing filtering.
4. It doesn't matter how many data is needed for filtering if your query is processes by one task/job. It has to also be able to work with null attributes if nothing is set for category or name.
5. When user added new requirement - filter filteredList for optimization.
6. Remember that, when you are clearing the letters - the list has to also change. This time you have no choice and has to filter originalList or make select on database.

But this is the most complicated way, which is used, when the list of item's can be very big. Otherwise you can simply select all of objects from the table in SQLite database as an oryginal list and work on it latter in the Java code.

The way of doing it depends from environemt so number of items, number of columns, lenght of the names etc. Try to find a way suitable to tour situation - I am sure, there is many articles in the network about it.